# How trigger changes in controller from a service WITHOUT employing $watch, $broadcast, $emit, etc

Tags: angularjs

I have a bunch of hierarchically arranged components, namely:

- partner component, that works with partner organizations, knows how to update or remove them, etc.;
- leader component, that works with leader organizations, knows how to deal with leader organizations;
- list component, than displays to the user both partner and leader organizations;
- a service - when partner or leader components removes an organization, info on this organization is passed to the list component so that these changes are reflected in front immediately.

I cannot provide code samples on this, it's too big, moreover my question mostly requires a conceptual advice rather than code issues. 
Right at the moment it perfectly works - components are doing their job sending data to the service:

```
  IndexCollection.setIndexes(
       vm.leaderIndex, vm.partnerIndex, 'added_l', response.id
  );
```

the service does it's job and pushed changes to a variable, which I `$watch` in the list component to trigger respective actions like this:

```
   $scope.$watch(() => IndexCollection.indexes, function() {
            let indexes = IndexCollection.indexes;

            switch (indexes.message) {
                case 'deleted_p':
                    removePartner(indexes);
                    break;
                case 'deleted_l':
                    removeLeader(indexes);
                    break;
                case 'added_l':
                    addLeader(indexes);
                    break;
            }
        });
```

My question is of a more theoretical essence. Is there a possibility to trigger real-time actions from service in the list component without using`$watch, $emit, $broadcast` and other standard tools we usually use in this regard?

Can I somehow achieve the same result by means of using callbacks? I mean, when a change in service occurs, it triggers immediate action in the respective controller?

Comment: I can't say as I've done this before, but I can't see any reason why you couldn't use `IndexCollection.subscribe((indices) => {});` and then manage the subscriptions how ever you want in your service.  Maybe someone that's tried has come across some issues with it, but logically it should work.

Answer (score 0):

While using $watch may solve the problem, it is not the most efficient solution. 
You might want to change the way you update and retrieve the data of your service.

The component controllers should manipulate the data stored in your service with functions in your service based on actions/events triggered from your component and you inject the service in the component.

```
MyDataService.getIndexCollection() {}
MyDataService.putIndexCollection() {}
```

Then you pass the data down to all your directives and components via require or bindings for components or isolated scopes for your directives.

For example once the partner components edits the data on the service you fetch the data again from your service and the updated data will be passed to your list component and update the view via $apply() if needed.